# Rename refactor doesn't work when the symbol is in a .razor file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, blazor, blazor-webassembly, omnisharp

I wanted to migrate to VS Code for my Blazor development, but this basic rename refactoring isn't working.

My Visual Studio Code version is 1.71.1

If I hit F2 on a property:
[image: F2 Rename]

And that property is referenced in .razor components within a @code block:

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        if (UserState.IsInitialized)
        {
         ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get this error popup, 'Rename failed to apply edits':

[image: Rename failed to apply edits]

If the variable is referenced only in 'normal' C# classes, renaming works fine.

I have C# for Visual Studio Code
and
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.VSCode.BlazorWasmDebuggingExtension

extensions installed.

I expect it will work if I make all my razor components have code-behind .cs files, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: What version of VS? Because "It works on my PC".

Comment: Yes, newer versions of VS 2022 are much better dealing with razor files than previous ones.

Comment: This is Visual Studio Code version 1.71.1 (latest release at time of writing)

Comment: OK, sorry, I missed the vs-code tags.